# How to enable compression for GraphQL API responses in AWS Appsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I've deployed a GraphQL API in AWS Appsync.

I observed that the API response I'm getting (JSON) is not being compressed, compressing the response will lower the latency time.

According to [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/enabling-caching.html),

> To enable compression, a client must send the Accept-Encoding header with the value gzip or br,

but even though I've sent the specified header, I'm getting the uncompressed data, which caused the delay in latency.

Any workaround to resolve this??

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue:
https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/15

The only known workaround seems to be to set up a CloudFormation for the Appsync where you are able to enable compression